# Update whole table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "customers" which looks like this:

```
ID   | NAME     | ADDRESS  | ZIP
John | Peterson | Street 2 | 45738
Jan  | 74383    | Street 4 | 74383
Eric | Stone    | 74383    | 74383
Julia| Carry    | Street 9 | 74383
```

I want to replace any occurrence of "74383" with "". I have about 1.5 Million rows. Is this doable?

Okay sorry that was my mistake, the number can be in any COLUMN! I updated it.

Comment: Do you want to update `ZIP` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange for me the requirement like this but, anyway, you can try this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE customers
SET NAME = ''
WHERE NAME = '74383';
UPDATE customers
SET ADDRESS = ''
WHERE ADDRESS = '74383';
UPDATE customers
SET ZIP = ''
WHERE ZIP = '74383';
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean in the `zip` column:

```
update customers
    set zip = ''
    where zip = '74383';
```

Note:  you might prefer to set the value to `NULL` rather than the empty string (`''`), but your question explicitly suggests an empty string.

EDIT:

I would actually suggest that you use separate `update` statements for each column if you have indexes on them.  The `updates` will be much faster.

Second, if you replace the value with `NULL` rather than `''`, you can use the logic:

```
update customers
    set zip = NULLIF(zip, '74383'),
        address = NULLIF(address, '74383'),
        name = NULLIF(name, '74383')
    where '74383' in (name, address, zip);
```

(You can actually replace this with an empty string using `COALESCE(NULLIF(zip, '74383'), '')`, but I prefer a `CASE` once the logic gets at all complicated.)

Comment: this is correct for only the zip column. Unfortunately the op changed the question on you :)

Comment: Is the predicate '74383' IN ( NAME, address, zip ) SARGable?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan . . . You might note that I suggest doing this as separate statements for just that reason.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the `IN` operator to search the existence of '74383' value in all the columns then using `case` statement you can update the columns. Try this.

```
UPDATE customers 
SET    NAME = CASE WHEN NAME = '74383' THEN '' ELSE NAME END, 
       address = CASE WHEN address = '74383' THEN '' ELSE address END, 
       zip = CASE WHEN zip = '74383' THEN '' ELSE zip END 
WHERE  '74383' IN ( NAME, address, zip )
```

Comment: Is the predicate `'74383' IN ( NAME, address, zip )` SARGable?